# Allocatable array valued function. gfortran vs ifort

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

Why is there different behavior between ifort and gfortran here? Compiled with ifort it returns false and with gfortran true. I ran into this problem before in my own code and decided to use a subroutine instead, but a recent question made me question this behavior.

```
function allocateArray(size)
    integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: allocateArray
    integer size

    allocate(allocateArray(size))

end function allocateArray
```

From the main program

```
integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: a

a = allocateArray(10)
print *, allocated(a)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When compiling with ifort before version 17.0.1, the default behaviour is for the compiler not to use the Fortran rules for automatic allocation on intrinsic assignment.

You will need to use an option like `-assume realloc-lhs`.